# Automatic choice of graphics format file for print command in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
X = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
Y = sin(X);
fh = figure('toolbar','none','menubar','none','Units','characters');
Pan1 = uipanel(fh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 0.5 1],'title',...
    'Panel1');
Pan2 = uipanel(fh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.5 0 0.5 1],'title',...
    'Panel2');
haxes = axes('Parent',Pan2,'Units', 'normalized','Position',...
[0.125 0.1 0.75 0.75]);
hplot = plot(haxes,X,Y);
xlabel(haxes,'Time (second)');
ylabel(haxes,'Amplitude (meter)');
title(haxes,'Sine function');
FileName = uiputfile('*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg;*.tif','Save as');
ftmp = figure('Menu','none','Toolbar','none','Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[-1000 -1000 1 1]);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off');
new_axes = copyobj(haxes, ftmp);
set(new_axes,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);
saveas(ftmp, FileName);
delete(ftmp);
delete(fh);
```

I have two problems:

Number #1: I want the background color of the figure printed to be gray. For this reason, I use the command

```
set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off');
```

However, when I save the image as a bmp format file, it appears an upper white strip on the image printed. This strip does not appear when the remaining formats (i.e., png, tif and jpg) are used.

Number #2: I want to change the command saveas by print and allow it to select the graphics format file automatically. One possibility is:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uiputfile('*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg;*.tif','Save as');
ftmp = figure('Menu','none','Toolbar','none','Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[-1000 -1000 1 1]);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off');
new_axes = copyobj(haxes, ftmp);
set(new_axes,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);
switch FilterIndex
    case 1 % graphics format file is bmp
        fmt = '-dbmp';
    case 2 % graphics format file is png
        fmt = '-dpng';
    case 4 % graphics format file is jpeg
        fmt = '-djpeg';
    otherwise % graphics format file is tiff
        fmt = '-dtiff';
end  
print(ftmp,fmt,FileName,'-r200');
delete(ftmp);
delete(fh);
```

What are the alternatives solutions to my problems? 
How I could change the line

```
print(ftmp,fmt,FileName,'-r200');
```

by

```
print -r200 fmt FileName;
```

without getting an error?

Comment: Just saw that you recently asked *another* question where the response was `export_fig`. You should *really* go get it.

Comment: @JohnColby: Thank you for your comment but export_fig has the same problem as the print command (you have to specify each graphics format file separately).

Comment: All you have to do is `export_fig myfig.png` and it saves it as a png. Similarly for jpg, pdf, etc.. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @JohnColby: Yes, it is. However, I would like to be able to write `export_fig fmt FileName` where fmt is the cell array with the graphics file formats and FileName is the string corresponding to uiputfile's command output but this does not work (actually export_fig is a improved better of print command and they have similar syntax).

Comment: Ahh thanks for the clarification. See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these issues (and *many* others) have already been addressed in the excellent [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) wrapper from FileExchange. I use it almost exclusively. Check it out, and I'm sure you'll like it too.

EDIT:

Thanks for the clarification in the comments to your question. This can still be handled with `export_fig`. If your output formats are in a cell array like `formats = {'png', 'jpg'}`, then you can just do something like:

```
eval(['export_fig myfig' reshape(char(strcat(' -', formats))', 1, [])])
```

It is a simple extension if you want to use the `FileName` variable:

```
eval(['export_fig ' FileName reshape(char(strcat(' -', formats))', 1, [])])
```

However, in that case, you'll probably first want to strip any extension the user added:

```
FileName = regexprep(FileName, '\.[\w]+$', '')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your edited answer. I still need that the name of the image file to be a entered variable (i.e. I need  FileName that is the string corresponding to uiputfile's command output). Can you edit your answer again?